# how to grab browser user agent and cookie and send this using cURL

Tags: php

I want to crawl a page. but the problem is this page is login Authenticated. so is there any way to use browser info. like i use my username and password to login and then create a script to use this information from my browser.

Comment: [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) to grab user agent

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. Post your credentials to login to the site and you should be able to crawl the site.